# .htaccess RewriteRule Problem: redirecting directory doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this simple .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^shop$ /apps/shop
```

So it should redirect this url
`http://192.168.0.221:8085/shop`
to that url
`http://192.168.0.221:8085/apps/shop`

But the server only gives Error 404.

Can't get it why?

Comment: That rule will _not_ redirect the browser, it will only internally rewrite the request. So the visible URL in the browser does not change. Not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: The http status 404 probably means that the rule does not get applied at all. So you need to check: is it implemented in the correct location (here a `.htaccess` file in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`), is the file readable for the http server process, does it contain anything else which might cause an issue? Do you get any entries in the http server's error log file and last not least: did you enable the interpretation of such files for that location (`AllowOverride` directive)?

Comment: Yes internally redirect is what I want...

Comment: there are a lot of rules after the one I mentioned working fine and are way more compley. I just don't wanted the questoion to be overloaded with working code

Comment: OH YOU DID IT arkascha! The htaccess I edited was not in the document root, thanks!

Comment: _Aside:_ Remove the two _conditions_ (`RewriteCond` directives). There's no point checking that the request does not map to a file or directory when you want to rewrite a specific URL. (If `/shop` was a physical directory then the rewrite does not happen.)

Comment: "The htaccess I edited was not in the document root" - Glad you got it sorted. You or @arkascha should add that as an answer (and later accept it) as this could help other readers (and removes this question from the unanswered question queue). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The htaccess I edited was not in the document root, thanks to @arkascha for this hint.